# How to close a window like p.e. a Firefox window, by bash and wid?

Tags: linux, bash, firefox

Envirement:

```
Linux like Ubuntu, bash
Firefox
```

Its known its possible to close all firefox windows by name:

```
pkill firefox
```

Its known its possible to close programms by:

```
kill -xx PID
```

Its known its not a good idea to close firefox tab by xdotool and sending a shortcut, depend on related bugs of xdotool. How ever, Closing a tab of active firefox windows is possible by hand on console, by follow, perhaps it give a idea for a other soluten:

```
Strg + w
```

Firefox can have more than one window, a not every firefox window have a own pid. A every firefox window have a own wid.

A list of actual firefox wid`s can get on follow way:

```
wmctrl -l | grep Firefox | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A window of a programm like p.e. a firefox window can closed by bash and wid on follow way:

```
wmctrl -i -c wid
```