# Does every Firefox tab have a own ID and how to get this ID by bash?

Tags: bash, firefox, id

Envirement:

- Linux like Ubuntu, Firefox
- bash

Its known programms like firefox have some pids, which can get p.e. on follow way:

```
pidof firefox
```

Its known every firefox window have a own wid, which can get on:

```
wmctrl -l | grep Firefox | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

Its known, a Firefox tab dont have a own pid or wid.

Does every Firefox tab have any other own ID and how to get this ID ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close a Firefox window by bash and wid?](https://superuser.com/questions/1694561/how-to-close-a-firefox-window-by-bash-and-wid)

Comment: @Toto, booth questions are related on different thinks.

Comment: "Its known, a Firefox tab dont have a own pid or wid." Who knows this? "It's known" isn't exactly a reference.

Comment: @mtak, its known by the people which writing this question.